# How do I communicate between microservices?

Tags: node.js, microservices

I have the following code in one microservices that calls another:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4210/usermicroservice/heartbeat')
 .then(function(resp) {
     console.log('USER HEARTBEAT CALLED ')
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('USER HEARTBEAT ERROR ', error)
})
```

In the called microservice I have the following code:

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
})

server.get('/usermicroservice/heartbeat', (req, res) => {
    console.log('\n*** USER MICROSERVICE CALLED ***')
    res.json({});
})

const PORT = 4210;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`hsupp01 UserMicroservice server running on port: ${PORT}`)
})
```

I get the following error:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4210
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 4210,
```

I am able to accessed the called microservice from Postman using the same url:

```
http://localhost:4210/usermicroservice/heartbeat
```

Comment: is the API running ?

Comment: yes, the api is running.

Comment: check the firewall settings whether that port is unblocked ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message does not capture the problem but the code below had to be executed within an asynchronous block.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4210/usermicroservice/heartbeat')
 .then(function(resp) {
     console.log('USER HEARTBEAT CALLED ')
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('USER HEARTBEAT ERROR ', error)
})
```